# Javascript Mocha test TypeError: x is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm using two js files to make a test with Mocha.

My **test.js** file looks like this:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const operations = require('./operations.js');

it('Calculates correct deserialization', () => {

  var leftLeft = new operations.Node('left.left', null, null);
  var left = new operations.Node('left', leftLeft, null);
  var right = new operations.Node('right', null, null);
  var root = new operations.Node('root', left, right);
  assert.equal(operations.deserialize(serialize(root)).left.left.val == 'left.left');
});
```

and my **operations.js** file looks like this:

```
function Node(val, left, right) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = left;
  this.right = right;
}
```

although incomplete, the test fails to instantiate the Node objects, and
exits with the message

> "TypeError: operations.Node is not a constructor"

I've already tried with

```
var leftLeft = new Node('left.left', null, null);
```

that is, without de `operations.Node()`.
I'm using strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to `require()` the file as a module, then you must export the function:

```
function Node(val, left, right) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = left;
  this.right = right;
}

module.exports = Node;
```